# entities not getting updated in @ngrx/data

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-ngrx-data

I am trying to learn @ngrx/data by creating simple TODO app

I created simple ToDoDataService to override default HTTP

```
@Injectable()
export class TodosDataService extends DefaultDataService<Todo> {

  constructor(httpClient: HttpClient, httpUrlGenerator: HttpUrlGenerator) {
    super('Todo', httpClient, httpUrlGenerator);
  }

  getAll(): Observable<Array<Todo>> {
    console.log('asfsfsfsf')
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
      .pipe(
        map((res: any) => res)
      );
  }

  getWithQuery(query): Observable<Array<any>> {
    console.log('asfsfsfsf', query);
    return this.http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?${query}`)
      .pipe(
        map((res: any) => res)
      );
  }    
}
```

In the route-resolver i am doing like this

```
@Injectable()
export class TodosResolver implements Resolve<boolean> {

  constructor(private todoService: TodoEntityService) {

  }
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean>  {

    return this.todoService.loaded$
      .pipe(
        tap(loaded => {
          if (!loaded) {
            this.todoService.getAll();
          }
        }),
        filter(loaded => !!loaded),
        first()
      );
  }

}
```

This is working fine and store/entities is updated

But in my component I am doing like this

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  loading$: Observable<boolean>;

  todos$: Observable<Todo[]>;

  constructor(
    private todoService: TodoEntityService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('dsdf');
    this.todos$ = this.todoService.entities$
      .pipe(
        tap(todos => {
          console.log(todos);
          this.loadMore();
          console.log(todos);

        }),
        map((todos: any) => todos),
        first()
      );
  }

  loadMore() {
    this.todoService.getWithQuery('_start=20&_limit=5');
  }

}
```

Here API is calling but entities is still showing old data. Not sure what i am doing wrong,

Please help

Comment: Good action hygiene - use a distinct, traceable and event driven names - something like `"[HomeComponent ONINIT] ONINIT"` then create effect that calls `loadMore()`. Otherwise you'll end up with just a QUERY_ALL that is hard to trace, especially of you call it in multiple places. Similarly with the resolver `"[TodosResolver RESOLVE] RESOLVE TODOS"`

Answer (score 3):

Welcome on @ngrx/data.

I suggest you to review the code snippet inside `ngOnInit`.
Here, you call `loadMore` method which implies a new Http request, each time the collection is updated.

Your code should look like this:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  // keep a local reference to observable of entities
  this.todos$ = this.todoService.entities$;

  // request a first load on view init
  this.loadMore();
}
```

In this way, the code inside `TodosResolver` is not really needed.

If you want to implement a **Load More** feature, you should react to another event (like scrolling or a click on button), and then call again `loadMore`.

Your observables like `entities$` or `loaded$` are just pipelines of data, and you shouldn't dispatch action when new values are emitted. 
If really needed, prefer to write a `@ngrx/effect`, it's done for that.

If you want to change the data or its format, you can use the `Observable` pipe for that, but not for calling a new action.

For example, this is ok:

```js
this.todos$ = this.todoService.entities$.pipe(
  map(entities => entities.map(entity => ({
    ...entity,
    authorName: entity.authorFirstname + ' ' + entity.authorLastName
  })));
);
```

Hope my answer is clear and will help you a little.

Comment: Very good answer...just want to add that `entities$` or `loaded$` and things that mapped with the pipe are called *selectors*. They should be pure getters and they fire anytime the relevant part of state fires. It's worth creating the view model selectors separately to ensure they benefit from memoization